# How to figure out the root cause for 409 Conflict when updating Azure resources concurrently (e.g. with terraform)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I use terraform to update my Azure infrastructure and get 409 Conflict when updating several resources. The error JSON is:

```
[
    {
        "Message": "Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress. Conflicting operation details: Id: XXX-XX-XX-XXX, OperationName: UpdateSite, CreatedTime: 1/15/2021 3:29:57 PM, WebSystemName: websites, SubscriptionName: YYY-YY-YY-YYY, WebspaceName: MyResourceGroup-EastUS2webspace, SiteName: MyAppServiceName, SlotName: Production, ServerFarmName: MyServicePlan, GeoOperationId: ZZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZZ"
    },
    {
        "Code": "Conflict"
    },
    {
        "ErrorEntity": {
            "Code": "Conflict",
            "ExtendedCode": "11008",
            "Message": "Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress. Conflicting operation details: Id: XXX-XX-XX-XXX, OperationName: UpdateSite, CreatedTime: 1/15/2021 3:29:57 PM, WebSystemName: websites, SubscriptionName: YYY-YY-YY-YYY, WebspaceName: MyResourceGroup-EastUS2webspace, SiteName: MyAppServiceName, SlotName: Production, ServerFarmName: MyServicePlan, GeoOperationId: ZZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZZ",
            "MessageTemplate": "Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress. Conflicting operation details: {0}",
            "Parameters": [
                "Id: XXX-XX-XX-XXX, OperationName: UpdateSite, CreatedTime: 1/15/2021 3:29:57 PM, WebSystemName: websites, SubscriptionName: YYY-YY-YY-YYY, WebspaceName: MyResourceGroup-EastUS2webspace, SiteName: MyAppServiceName, SlotName: Production, ServerFarmName: MyServicePlan, GeoOperationId: ZZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZZ"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I want to understand exactly what operation caused this conflict. So, I went to Azure Portal to inspect the MyResourceGroup:

[image]

Excellent, I can see the failed operation. But examining the details does not yield anything new at all:

[image]

The JSON tab contains a lot of stuff, but I do not see how it helps me.

I use terraform and the plan in a nutshell is:

```
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service.webapp["centralus-backoffice"] will be updated in-place
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service.webapp["centralus-gateway"] will be updated in-place
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service.webapp["centralus-portal"] will be updated in-place
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service.webapp["eastus2-backoffice"] will be updated in-place
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service.webapp["eastus2-gateway"] will be updated in-place
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service.webapp["eastus2-portal"] will be updated in-place
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_certificate.cert["centralus"] must be replaced
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_certificate.cert["eastus2"] must be replaced
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["centralus-backoffice"] must be replaced
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["centralus-gateway"] must be replaced
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["centralus-portal"] must be replaced
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["eastus2-backoffice"] must be replaced
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["eastus2-gateway"] must be replaced
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["eastus2-portal"] must be replaced
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_plan.asp["centralus"] will be updated in-place
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_plan.asp["eastus2"] will be updated in-place
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting.webapp_autoscale["centralus"] will be created
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting.webapp_autoscale["eastus2"] will be created
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.AppSvcLogging["centralus-backoffice"] will be created
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.AppSvcLogging["centralus-gateway"] will be created
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.AppSvcLogging["centralus-portal"] will be created
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.AppSvcLogging["eastus2-backoffice"] will be created
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.AppSvcLogging["eastus2-gateway"] will be created
# module.web.module.web.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.AppSvcLogging["eastus2-portal"] will be created
```

Now when the plan is applied I can see this:

```
2021-01-15T15:29:56.5352272Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["eastus2-portal"]: Destroying...
2021-01-15T15:29:57.4811573Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["eastus2-backoffice"]: Destroying...
2021-01-15T15:29:57.4821608Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["centralus-gateway"]: Destroying...
2021-01-15T15:29:57.4822152Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["centralus-portal"]: Destroying...
2021-01-15T15:29:57.4822571Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["eastus2-gateway"]: Destroying...
2021-01-15T15:29:57.4822967Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["centralus-backoffice"]: Destroying...
2021-01-15T15:29:57.4823321Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_plan.asp["eastus2"]: Modifying...
2021-01-15T15:29:57.4824061Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_plan.asp["centralus"]: Modifying...
2021-01-15T15:29:58.9215681Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["eastus2-gateway"]: Destruction complete after 2s
2021-01-15T15:29:59.0340631Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["eastus2-portal"]: Destruction complete after 2s
2021-01-15T15:29:59.1736507Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["centralus-gateway"]: Destruction complete after 2s
2021-01-15T15:29:59.1888546Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["centralus-portal"]: Destruction complete after 2s
2021-01-15T15:29:59.2594031Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["centralus-backoffice"]: Destruction complete after 2s
2021-01-15T15:30:04.2048254Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.webapp_fqdn["eastus2-backoffice"]: Destruction complete after 7s
2021-01-15T15:30:04.2117820Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_certificate.cert["centralus"]: Destroying...
2021-01-15T15:30:04.2128930Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_certificate.cert["eastus2"]: Destroying...
2021-01-15T15:30:06.1069854Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_certificate.cert["eastus2"]: Destruction complete after 2s
2021-01-15T15:30:06.1795563Z module.web.module.web.azurerm_app_service_certificate.cert["centralus"]: Destruction complete after 2s
```

(I removed the ids output by terraform)

And then it blows up for both App Service Plans (eastus2 and centralus).

There must be a way to figure out what conflicted with what. How can one do it? I am OK with az cli or Az Powershell or Azure Portal.

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot, there are only two cases, one is when terraform is used, it is executed twice. The second is that when using terraform, there is a bug on the azure side (the probability is very small and needs to be confirmed by rasie a support ticket, because the time difference in the log is only within 1 second).